# Regridding GEOTIFF to lower resolution with rasterio in Python

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm attempting to take a 0.05 X 0.05 degree raster in .tif format and regrid it to 0.25 X 0.25 degrees (a factor of 5). I'm using rasterio to do this with the code below

```
with rio.open("/Volumes/TAMU_HD/CAPEstudy/PFI_NoFringe1.tif") as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.height / 5., dataset.width / 5., dataset.count),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c44a7a5e1041> in <module>
      2     data = dataset.read(
      3         out_shape=(dataset.height / 5., dataset.width / 5., dataset.count),
----> 4         resampling=Resampling.bilinear
      5     )

rasterio/_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read()

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any advice on regridding in rasterio or if there are suggestions for other packages that might do this easier? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like rasterio can't use float shape dimensions. So either remove point after 5 or cast new shape to int.

Comment: out_shape=(int(dataset.height / 5), int(dataset.width / 5), dataset.count),